# How can I draw the control points of a Bézier Path in Java?

Tags: java, drawing, vector-graphics, bezier, java-2d

I have created a Path of Bézier curves and it works fine to draw the path. But I don't know How I can draw the Control Points together with the Path. Is that possible or do I have to keep track of them in another datastructure?

**Update:** The reason to why I want to draw the control points, is that I will let the user to edit the curves using handles on the control points.

I am creating the path with:

```
Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(0,0);
path.curveTo(5, 6, 23, 12, 45, 54);
path.curveTo(34, 23, 12, 34, 2, 3);
```

And drawing it with:

```
g2.draw(path);
```

I have tested with **PathIterator** as *trashgod* suggested, but it will be hard to manage the curves that way if I want the user to be able to edit the control points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain a [`PathIterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html) to reference the array of coordinates for each point in the `Shape`. You can use these to draw resize handles and control points along the curve when editing. Here's an [example](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/gfx/bezier.html) of editing using a custom curve implementation.

Comment: You are right about PathIterator, but I think I will change my representation because I want to let the user edit the curves, and it will be hard to handle with only a Path-representation.

Comment: Why not keep both: the `Path` for rendering convenience and the derived geometry for editing? You'd have to refresh the latter when adding or removing points.