# How to calculate the length of a Path2D in Java?

Tags: java, geometry, java-2d, graphics2d

I have some paths represented by Path2D. The Path consist of multiple CubicCurve2D or Line2D segments that are connected to each other. I would like to calculate or get the length from the start to the end of a Path. How can I calculate it or get it? Is it possible? I have checked [the API documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html), but couldn't find any useful methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In light of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533565) on this topic, the article [*Computing the Arc Length of Cubic Bezier Curves*](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html) may offer some insight. For convenience, you may want to look at the JScience [`Polynomial`](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/function/Polynomial.html) class. Also, this [approximation](http://www.lemoda.net/maths/bezier-length/index.html), based on the same [article](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/curves/cbezarclen.html), may help.

Answer (score 3):

Start by using `getPathIterator()` to get the path elements. If the path only has `SEG_MOVETO` and `SEG_LINETO` elements, the length should be easy to calculate. Just sum sqrt((X1-X2)^2 + (Y1-Y2)^2) for all of the `SEG_LINETO`, where point (X1, Y1) was the previous endpoint, and (X2, Y2) is the current one returned by currentSegment(double[]).

If it also contains `SEG_QUADTO` or `SEG_CUBICTO` elements, that will require a more complicated formula that I don't care to figure out right now (may require calculus).

Comment: +1 for checking the type to simplify calculations. I initially favored the `Polynomial` class for it's calculus methods, but the arc length integral has no closed form solution. :-(

Answer (score 1):

First of all sorry for my english...

I know this is an old topic but perhaps it's useful for someone.
I made this, is not for a CubicCurve but for a QuadCurve:

```
public double CurveLength (QuadCurve curve){
    double xini = curve.getStartX();
    double yini = curve.getStartY();
    double xpoint = curve.getControlX();
    double ypoint = curve.getControlY();
    double xfin = curve.getEndX();
    double yfin = curve.getEndY();

    double ax = xini-(2*xpoint)+xfin;
    double ay = yini-(2*ypoint)+yfin;
    double bx = (2*xpoint)-(2*xini);
    double by = (2*ypoint)-(2*yini);
    double A = 4*((ax*ax)+(ay*ay));
    double B = 4*((ax*bx)+(ay*by));
    double C = (bx*bx)+(by*by);

    double Sabc = 2*(Math.sqrt(A+B+C));
    double A2 = Math.sqrt(A);
    double A32 = 2*A*A2;
    double C2 = 2*(Math.sqrt(C));
    double BA = B/A2;

    double length = ((A32*Sabc) + (A2*B*(Sabc-C2)) + (((4*C*A)-(B*B))*Math.log(((2*A2)+BA+Sabc)/(BA+C2))))/(4*A32);
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function 
public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at, double flatness);

This will give a 'flattenend' iterator containing only SEG_MOVETO, SEG_LINETO, and SEG_CLOSE segments.